# How to put spaces in between a for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am wondering how to put a space in between each array item when printing to the console. I have tried messing with the `countries[i]` but I usually get an error in the console.

```js
var countries = ["France", "Germany", "Austria"]
var i
var s = ""

for (i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
  s += countries[i]
}

console.log(s)
```

Comment: `console.log(countries.join(' '));`

Comment: Do you want `countries.join(' ')`?

Answer (score 2):

Using `.join()`:

```js
var countries = ["France", "Germany", "Austria"];
var spaced = countries.join(' ');
console.log(spaced);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `join`:

Ex:
`countries.join(' ');`

or concat a space on the end:

`s += countries[i] + ' '`

Answer (score 0):

So you want following as the end result?

> France Germany Austria

There is a function in JavaScript to concatenate all elements of an array into a new string:

```
join()
```

More info on this function: [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

By default the ',' is the separator but you can also specify one, such as a space. So this is the way to do it:

```js
var countries = ["France", "Germany", "Austria"];
var countryString = countries.join(' ');
console.log(countryString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

```
let a = ["France", "Germany", "Austria"];
let s = '';
for (let s2 of a) {
   if (s != '') {
      s += ' ';
   }
   s += s2;
}
console.log(s);
```

or you could just Join:

```
let s = a.join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use **Spread Operator** during console logging. In your case use,

```
console.log(...countries);
```

Answer (score 0):

You essentially just need to concat a space character to the end of each string you are adding

```
var countries = ["France", "Germany", "Austria"]
var i
var s = ""

for (i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
  s += countries[i] + " "
}

console.log(s)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do it in a better way as follows using the [**`join()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method provided by JavaScript -

```js
var countries = ["France", "Germany", "Austria"]

// Alternative better way -
var s = countries.join(' ')

console.log(s)

// Your method is unnecessarily long but can be done as -

/* 
var i;
var s = ""

 for(i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) { 
  s += countries[i];
  if(i !== countries.length -1)
    s+= " ";
}

*/
```

As a side tip, whenever you use JavaScript, try to see if you can use the built-in methods provided in JS. Most of the situation could be handled using an inbuilt method and you would never need to use an explicit `for` loop for most of the time.